# Reverse of all() in R

Tags: r

I want to create a variable 'oth' which is TRUE if none of the variables 'com', 'edit' or 'cont' are TRUE. The three variables are logical vectors taking the values TRUE or FALSE.

I tried to do 2 things:

```
data$oth  <- all(!data$com, !data$edit, !data$cont)
data$oth  <- all(data$com==F, data$edit==F, data$cont==F)
```

None worked, i.e., $oth was just a vector of all FALSE. Are there an reverse to the all() function in R or how should I do this?

Comment: Try `any()` maybe.

Comment: Try `!all(...)`? If you share reproducible data it will help us help you

Comment: any() won't work, as I need all to be FALSE, not just 1.
!all() produces a vector of all TRUE, so does not work either

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `!any`.

```
!any(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
#[1] FALSE

!any(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
#[1] FALSE

!any(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
#[1] TRUE

!any(c(FALSE, FALSE), c(FALSE, FALSE), c(FALSE, FALSE))
#[1] TRUE

!any(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(FALSE, FALSE), c(FALSE, FALSE))
#[1] FALSE
```

But it looks like that you want a result per row.

```
!(c(FALSE, FALSE) | c(FALSE, FALSE) | c(FALSE, FALSE))
#[1] TRUE TRUE

!(c(TRUE, FALSE) | c(FALSE, FALSE) | c(FALSE, FALSE))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
data$oth  <- all(data$com==F) & all(data$edit==F) & all(data$cont==F)
```

Comment: Bad practice.. first using `F` instead of `FALSE`, second using `== FALSE` instead of simply `!`.

Comment: Ooooh, look at you. GREAT CATCH!

Answer (score 0):

To match your criteria of assigning `TRUE` if **all** values in the row are `FALSE` you can simply use:

```
dt$oth <- rowSums(dt) == 0
```